# Integral of join posterior distribution wrt to mean for normal with conjugate priors

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian

The last line in the following block shows the join posterior distribution for the mean $\mu$ and precision $\tau$ for a normal distribution:

[image: posterior]

In order to obtain the marginal posterior for $\tau$ we need to integrate out $\mu$. However, I haven't been able to find a step by step solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you mean you want to know how to integrate the last line with respect to $\mu$ over $[-\infty,\infty]$?

Comment: Yes. Every book I have found on the topic glosses over it. Specifically, what the steps to get a symbolic solution are before evaluating it at those limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Complete the square in the final exponential of your last line until you can write
$$
p(\tau,\mu|x)\propto f(\tau)\exp\left\{-\frac{\tau \cdot \rho}{2}(\mu-m)^2\right\},
$$
for some values $\rho$ and $m$, and now use the familiar Gaussian integral.

Can fill in more details if/when you need, but really there isn't much more going on here than completing the square until you have a recognisable Gaussian, with some slightly tedious, but probably worth doing, keeping track of those terms involving $\tau$.